# In Sales Order Grid I want to hide the view Link

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

[image]

when order status is complete . View link should be there if status is pending How to it condition on grid.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: it's Very Easy you need to Override the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` as per magento Standrads.

or

You can Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`
to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`

**Step 2**:Now you need to open that file and search `_prepareColumns()` method.

**Step 3**: In that function Search Below Code.

```
 if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                        'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                        'field'   => 'order_id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));
    }
```

**Step 4**: Comment that code & Check your sales Order Grid.

let me know if you have any Query.

Comment: every time not a solution to using local pool change a core file so try to extend a functionality using observer.

Comment: I Agree with you each time is not good but they Need to just remove that link if there is highly customization then they need to override the that Grid. that's y I mention First option to override grid @ravipatel

Comment: Keyul @ i need view link only when status is "Pending".once status is Complete i want to hide the view link

Comment: Then You need to do More customization and you need to used the rendered in magento then you can achieve this kind of feature

Comment: Can we have any process to achieve that to use renderer i tried but its not working

Answer (score 1):

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <module>
            <class>Vendor_Module_Block</class>
        </module>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>Vendor_Module_Block_Rewrite_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Rewrite class:

```
class Vendor_Module_Block_Rewrite_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        return $this->removeColumn('action');
    }
}
```